Question on SOT integrability
I am studying vector valued $H^p$ spaces from Nikolski's book. Here's a question that I have:
Let $( \Omega , \mathcal{A} , \mu )$ be a measure space and $Y,Z$ be Banach spaces. A function $f : \Omega \to \mathcal{L} (Y,Z)$ is called SOT integrable if $f(\cdot) y$ is Bochner integrable for every $y \in Y$.
Nikolski then writes that it follows that the operator $V : y \mapsto \int_{\Omega} f(s)y  d\mu (s)$ is bounded operator from $Y$ to $Z$. However, this is not immediate to me. My attempt was to use Closed graph theorem but I do not see how it works.
Hints in proving this would be appreciated!

[EDIT] It seems like closed graph theorem cannot be directly used on $V$. We consider the operator $T : Y \to L^1 (\Omega; Z)$ (the $Z$-valued $L^1$ functions) given by $(Ty)(s) = f(s)y$ for each $y\in Y$. Now, we show that $T$ is a bounded operator using the closed graph theorem.
Let $y_n \to y$ in $Y$ and suppose that $Ty_n \to g$ in $L^1 (\Omega ; Z)$.  It is clear that $Ty_n$ converges to $Ty$ pointwise. If it were the case that convergence in $L^1 (\Omega; X)$ implied the existence of the subsequence which converges pointwise a.e. then $g=Ty$ a.e. and we are done.
Then we would have that $\lVert V \rVert = \sup_{\lVert y\rVert \le 1} \lVert Vy \rVert = \sup_{\lVert y\rVert \le 1} \lVert \int_{\Omega} f(s) y d\mu (s) \rVert \le \sup_{\lVert y\rVert \le 1}  \int_{\Omega} \lVert f(s) y \rVert d\mu (s) = \lVert T \rVert$.
I suspect that it is true that convergence in $L^1 (\Omega; X)$ implies the existence of the subsequence which converges pointwise a.e. But I would like to see some references which prove this fact.

Can't you apply the scalar case? If $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L_1(Ω,X)$ then $g_n=|f_n-f|$ converges to zero in $L_1(Ω)$ hence $g_n$ converges to zero a.e. for a subsequence.

@EvangelopoulosFoivos That's right. That evaded me!

What you have done with the closed graph theorem looks fine. It is true that if a sequence $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f$ in $L^{1}(\Omega , X)$ then there is a subsequence of $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which converges pointwise almost everywhere to $f$.
One way to show this is to consider the sequence $(g_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of scalar-valued functions where $g_{n} := \|f_{n} - f\|$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $(g_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a subsequence converging pointwise almost everywhere to $0$ and the result follows by noting that this is equivalent to the sequence $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converging to $f$ pointwise almost everywhere.
Another way is to directly prove the result. There is a proof in Chapter VI, Theorem 5.2 on page 138 of "Real and Functional Analysis" by Lang. The proof is essentially the same as the standard one.
